# Selecting only Bold style data using javascript or HTML from a given text

Tags: javascript

I have a request coming in for the javascript coding and since I am very new to the javascript i am asking for some help in here.

The original text I receive in a column of csv file is in the format -

```
By <b>AAA</b>this is a test <b>BBB</b>this is a test2 <b>CCC</b>this is a test3
```

But I want to transform it using JS in the format -

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Is there any way I can extract just the data that is in bold tags while deleting rest of the data, and also adding break between each finally selected text?

I would need to use this reduced data in an HTML page, so if there is a possibility of using some HTML coding, that is also quite welcome.

Comment: is not a clear question so probably you will get a lot of down-votes. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, how to make good questions.

Comment: Regular expressions might be a good tool for this. But we'd need a better description of the string that you want to parse and the information that you want to get out of it.

Comment: Please paste a sample of your actual data file. Also, are you trying to run this code in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the string inside an HTML element then use getElementsByTagName() to get the elements with the specific tag you want;

```js
var str = 'By <b>AAA</b>this is a test <b>BBB</b>this is a test2 <b>CCC</b>this is a test3';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var boldElements = div.getElementsByTagName('b');
for (i = 0; i < boldElements.length; i++) {
    document.write(boldElements[i].innerHTML + '<br>\n');
}
```